# How to open a tag and close the tag in conditionally in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) in my project. So I want to use this in conditionally in my render.

Please check the below codes:

**I know it will work**:

```
render() {
    var zoomHandlers;
    if (this.props.windowTitle === "Zoom") {
      zoomHandlers = true;
    } else {
      zoomHandlers = false;
    }
    return (
      <div id={this.props.windowID}>
        {zoomHandlers ? (
          <TransformWrapper>
            <TransformComponent>
              <div className="content" style={contStyle}>
                Lot of lines are here.......
              </div>
            </TransformComponent>
          </TransformWrapper>
        ) : (
          <div className="content" style={contStyle}>
            Lot of lines here.......
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**But I'm trying to do like this:**

```
 render() {
    var zoomHandlers;
    if (this.props.windowTitle === "Zoom") {
      zoomHandlers = true;
    } else {
      zoomHandlers = false;
    }
    return (
      <div id={this.props.windowID}>
        {
          zoomHandlers ? (
          <TransformWrapper>
            <TransformComponent>)
              : null }
              <div className="content" style={contStyle}>
                Lot of lines are here.......
              </div>
              {zoomHandlers ? (    
            </TransformComponent>
          </TransformWrapper>): null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It's showing error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token `</TransformComponent>`
>                                      ^

Actually I don't want to repeat the same code again and again, same like I added the working code above. Is this possible?

Comment: Your content inside `return()` make no sense. Please check the code and make sure all the `()`, `{}` are closed and proper with the conditional operator.

Comment: @keikai It's not depending on (),{} close, I'm asking is this possible in open component tag and close tag in render or not?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, **NO**. JSX doesn't work this way.

But can you do the same thing you do most other times you repeat code? **YES**

Apply DRY-principle: Factor out the repeated code into a function or component.

```
renderRepeatedJSX = () => (
  <div className="content" style={contStyle}>
    Lot of lines are here.......
  </div>
);

render() {
  const zoomHandlers = this.props.windowTitle === "Zoom"
  return (
    <div id={this.props.windowID}>
      {zoomHandlers ? (
        <TransformWrapper>
          <TransformComponent>
            { this.renderRepeatedJSX() }
          </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>
      ) : this.renderRepeatedJSX()
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit empty-dream-qu4s3]

Comment: I'm looking the answer like this, thank you... but It's also showing `Parsing error: Unexpected token` on  `const renderRepeatedJSX`.

Comment: Ah, class component? Drop the `const` then. Sorry m8. Updated answer.

Comment: I tried this already... then the error in `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{" ` on `{ renderRepeatedJSX() }`

Comment: `renderRepeatedJSX` becomes an instance function, call like `this.renderRepeatedJSX()`.

Comment: I tried this way too, and I bind it in constructor also... then the error is `Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'`

Comment: Yup, tested this out to see what else may unkink, just remove the  parenthesis and curly brackets in the false branch. Already updated answer. (*apologies, been a while since I worked with class-based components, but that's what IDE's with linters are for, right?*)

Comment: Thank you so much, You made my day... Can I ask  one thing, there is no sense in my question?

Comment: I think it was a valid issue, if that is what you're asking. I know ternaries can be a little tricky to understand, especially after getting mixed with JSX.